# NameError in simple python code

Tags: python, string, undefined, palindrome, nameerror

This is a simple palindrome checker. The code works for numbers, but not strings.

```
x = str(input("Enter a number: "))
if x == x[::-1]:
    print x + " is a palindrome!"
else:
    print x + " is not a palindrome!"
```

When I try inputting a string, I get this error:

```
  File "palindrome.py", line 1, in <module>
    x = str(input("Enter a number: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'abba' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are using Python 2.x!

Please use `raw_input` for keyboard input. This always returns a string, so there is no need to cast/convert.

In Python 2.x `input` tries to evaluate the text entered as Python, and you never defined abba, so it will cause a `NameError`

See [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) for more.

Comment: And the `str()` can be dropped; `raw_input()` returns a string, always.

Answer (score 0):

Where you input some numbers.For example,"Enter a number: 1221".you can get

> x=str(1221)

it's rigth.

But, "Enter a number: abba".you can get

> x=str(abba)

it's wrong.Beacuse the "abba" is not string, and is not defined.

you can try "Enter a number: 'abba'", or use

> raw_input('Enter a number:')

replace input("Enter a number: ")
and You can get the results you want.

read more information on [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#raw_input)